# Auto paste clipboard on load page @ chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a website that the main issue in it is pasting stuff from clipboard, and an extension for that.

I want to auto-paste clipboard content when a specific page is opened.

For some reason the execCommand("Paste") is not executed when the page is loaded.

**content.js**

```
setTimeout(function() { chrome.extension.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"},function(response){}); },200);
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
document.execCommand("Paste");
  sendResponse({});
  return true;
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
  "page": "src/bg/background.html",
  "persistent": true
},
"options_page": "src/options/index.html",
"permissions": [
  "clipboardRead",
  "clipboardWrite",
  "fileBrowserHandler",
  "*my website address*"
],
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": [
        "*my website address*"
    ],
"js": ["js/content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
}
]
```

everything works great until the paste is needed to be done and it's just not working...

thanks :)

Comment: Do you have something showing in the javascript console?

Comment: like an error? nope..

Answer (score 0):

http://caniuse.com/#search=clipboardData

There says that "paste" command is not fired by using document.execCommand('paste')

Apparently there are other ways to make copy & paste but it all depends on compatibility.
I am still browsing around looking for a nice solution.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but here's Google's tutorial on the Clipboard API:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi

Apparently, you need a variable to hold the result of `document.execCommand('paste')`:

```
button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.value = text;
  input.focus();
  input.select();
  const result = document.execCommand('copy');
  if (result === 'unsuccessful') {
    console.error('Failed to copy text.');
  }
})
```